# ¿como puedo modificar un archivo xml, eliminar y sobre escribir un hijo, en java?

Tags: java, xml

Tengo un proyecto en eclipse basado en JAVA, en este proyecto dispongo de un archivo XML donde guardo datos de personal de enfermería, lo que quiero es eliminar una enfermera (un hijo) de este archivo, también quiero sobre escribir en estos datos. 
favor darme ejemplos, alguna solución. 
gracias.

Answer (score 3):

Java tiene [varios](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java_xml/java_dom_parse_document.htm) componentes que pueden ser útiles para localizar un elemento y alterar un documento XML. Ya que no mencionas mas detalles de cual de ellos estas usando te ofrezco un ejemplo con el método que mejor conozco:

```
// 1. cargar el XML original
DocumentBuilderFactory factory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
DocumentBuilder builder = factory.newDocumentBuilder();
Document doc = builder.parse(new File("ruta/al/archivo.xml");

// 2. buscar y eliminar el elemento <enfermera id="3"> de entre 
//    muchos elementos <enfermera> ubicados en cualquier posicion del documento
NodeList items = doc.getElementsByTagName("enfermera");
for (int ix = 0; ix < items.getLength(); ix++) {
    Element element = (Element) items.item(ix);
    // elejir un elemento especifico por algun atributo
    if (element.getAttribute("id").equalsIgnoreCase("3")) {
        // borrar elemento
        element.getParentNode().removeChild(element);
    }
}

// 3. Exportar nuevamente el XML
Transformer transformer = TransformerFactory.newInstance().newTransformer();
Result output = new StreamResult(new File("ruta/a/resultado.xml"));
Source input = new DOMSource(doc);
transformer.transform(input, output);
```

Espero que te ayude.